# Type inference on function parameters with nested generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am facing an issue with Typescript generics.

I have a function which must be called with a type and some attributes depending on this type.
Typescript does not manage to infer the type of attributes when inside an if guarding the type to `TYPES.ME`:

```
enum TYPES {
    ME = 'me',
    YOU = 'you'
}

type Attributes<T extends TYPES> =  T extends TYPES.ME ? {keys: true} : {hat: true}
const func = <T extends TYPES>(type: T, attr: Attributes<T>) => {
    if(type === TYPES.ME) {
        attr.keys // error Property 'keys' does not exist on type '{ keys: true; } | { hat: true; }'
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgmgBQKIGUoG8BQUdQLJJQC8UA5BMKQDTa5wDyAqsWQJ4D2YpmAvppgBdWAB2BQAggIEAnAJYAjMAOABnADwwowAB7KQAExWxEqAHwtYW3aEPHkKAHQEoAfgwBrYKxUAuKDLBgHig-dAALAEMBPwCgzABjdhAVASgAMzAQeJYNKz1beHtTAAohUT8YKigomT9JGQUlVQ1TAEpicyxcKFk00pExIiG7VCckdq7u3BrpB09vWhw%20YMwgA)

I would like to have your opinions on this matter and see if there is a nice workaround.

Cheers!

Comment: ① Please consider changing the word "asserting" to something like "guarding"; the `if` check is neither a type assertion (e.g., `as` to assume it's true) nor a runtime assertion (e.g., `throw` if not true) so it's confusing.

Comment: ② I can call `func(Math.random() < 0.999 ? TYPES.ME : TYPES.YOU, { hat: true })` so the compiler is technically correct to warn; generics aren't really able to deal with case analysis in the body. You can change to a discriminated union rest param as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbl99w). Does that fully address the question? If so then I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I was hoping to find a template not needing modifications for each new type. In your example, a new array must be added to `FuncArgs` for every new type to handle. Any idea for a way to do this with any kind of pattern?

Comment: Your example has `T extends TYPES.ME ? {keys: true} : {hat: true}` which surely needs modifications for each type.  Seems like you might be asking a followup question now, which is out of scope.  Can we keep the scope as asked in the question and I can post an answer?  Or do you want to [edit] the question so that it asks specifically what you're trying to ask (is it about "generics" or is it about "not needing modifications for each new type")?  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: Yes sure post your answer, it is the explanation for my question. I will try to come up with a new question that fits my need and fits in your strict scope ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, TypeScript is unable to re-constrain [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters as a result of [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  Inside the body of `func(type, attr)`, you check that `type === Types.ME`.  This can [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `type` from `T` to something like `T & Types.ME`.  **But it cannot do anything to `T` itself.**  The type parameter `T` stubbornly stays the same; it is not constrained to `Types.ME`. And thus the compiler cannot conclude that `attr` is of type `Attributes<Types.ME>`.

And it is technically correct for the compiler to refuse to change `T`.  That's because, while individual values like `type` can only be one thing at a time, a type argument like `T` can be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Indeed, you can call `func()` with a `T` equal to the full `Types.ME | Types.YOU` union, like so:

```
func(
    Math.random() < 0.999 ? Types.ME : Types.YOU,
    { hat: true }
) // compiles without error
```

If you inspect that, you'll see that `T` is inferred as `Types` (the full union of `Types.ME | Types.YOU`, and therefore `attr` is allowed to be `{hat: true}` even in the 99.9% likely event that `type` is `Types.ME`.

There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) which asks for a way to say "`T` will be exactly one of `Types.ME` or `Types.YOU`; it cannot be a union".  And then, maybe inside the function body, checking `type === Types.ME` would allow `T` itself to be constrained to `Types.ME`, and things would work as expected.  And presumably the call with `Math.random() < 0.999` would be rejected.

But for now it's not part of the language.

---

You might consider taking the approach where instead of having `func` be generic, you make it similar to an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function, where it has one call signature per member of `Types`. You can write that as a function with a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types), and the compiler will [treat it as such inside the function body](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).

Perhaps like this:

```
type FuncArg =
    [type: Types.ME, attr: { keys: true }] |
    [type: Types.YOU, attr: { hat: true }];

const func: (...args: FuncArg) => void = (type, attr) => {
    if (type === Types.ME) {
        console.log(attr.keys) // this works
    }
}
```

And now you can't make the invalid call:

```
func(
    Math.random() < 0.999 ? Types.ME : Types.YOU,
    { hat: true }
) // error, type 'Types.ME' is not assignable to type 'Types.YOU'
```

Everything works because now `type` and `attr` are bound together as desired in `FuncArg`; it's like imagining `T` were constrained to be just one member of `Types` at a time, and walking through the possibilities.  Note that `FuncArg` could, if necessary, be computed from the `Attributes` type given in the question, or from another mapping interface, but that is out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAKgTwA4gM4wN7BjmBZAURgF4YByKEMgGm1wE0B5AVRPIQHsIzgBfYYGACGlVEiEBjEDEYck6LLhgAXZNICCy5QCcAlgCMIytAB44MEAA9jYACbpEKVAD425qzfvw1qAHSEYAH5MGABrEARUAC4VbQhpXhgYjBgACyFlGJ14mH4lCQ4wVGUYADMIMAk2MwtrcC9HNGcAClUUGLhqGAydGM0dAyNTOGcAShJXRSVcXVKYVrUSYlJGv0JxqenpgqKOABsQXz2OAHNmnu1fcMjxgHpbi21tDm06Lbzcfjeyiolm76UeAyqV82iEdg4UGa4xMMAADL4AJzIoLeJz+IgdHy+JjMWhbHApdKZWI5D44O4PZSpXToWkwJAcVCoAwHARfATCUTiKQwZhgXSFBTfNrSABiv3U2hOJABuAA2qKsejCF0LskwhFoqSEgBdGAAHzlOEVamVaBxLDVWm0GuJWTieoA3N8dsUfpUYs1fD6hNLtRLKlKTuNiK4AG4cXS2NgLFDWnShybGmCzeaipYrbHrTAp-JC-aHY5nC5XLWUlQ09AAdxeoVQKfJuQESnKlX+BPwwNB4NskOhMFhCORiNRqwxSTRFtx+IJRIyDrJ3wrICeLy6GbI48IZFT6DAHBKQmZuhOwn0BxUHBUiy32NxPD4QA)